# Why does adonis2() vegan function in R reproduces NA/NaN/inf error?

Tags: r, vegan

When doing adonis2() function with a matriz with in the same composition has "Rstudio" dune dataframe I've come across an NA/NaN/inf error

I have: 
1.Arranged my data-frames as shown in adonis2() help with dune data
2.Checked with `str()` and `class()` to ensure the matrix was a `data.frame` and the values were either numeric or factores (depending on the scores or environment matrix)

EXAMPLE DATA:

```
scores.eg = data.frame("a" = c(1, NA, 3, 4, 5),
                     "b" = c(NA, 0, 1, 1, 3),
                     "c" = c(4, 4, 2, 3, NA))
scores.env.eg = data.frame("decade" = c(1970, 1980, 1990, 2000, 2010))
```

INPUT:

```
adonis2(scores.eg ~ decade, data = scores.env.eg, na.action = na.omit)
```

OUTPUT:

```
Error in vegdist(as.matrix(lhs), method = method, ...) : 
      NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 1)
```

After replacing all NAs with 0s I got this result:

EXPECTED RESULT:

```
Permutation test for adonis under reduced model
Terms added sequentially (first to last)
Permutation: free

adonis2(scores.eg ~ decade, data = scores.env.eg, na.action = na.omit)
               Df SumOfSqs      F Pr(>F)   
year.capture    1    5.017 184.38   0.01 **
Residual     1523   41.437                 

Signif. codes:  0 ‘’ 0.001 ‘’ 0.01 ‘’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1`
```

Comment: Have you tried to set the `na.action` argument in `adonis2`? The default action is `na.fail` which tells `adonis2` to fail if there are missing values. Try, say `na.action = na.omit`.

Comment: @MrFlick I've now created an example to better explain the problem, thank you for the suggestion, will do now everytime

Comment: @JariOksanen indeed I've tried and added in the new input, same error

Comment: More errors: `scores.eg`  has 5 observations, `scores.eg.env` has 3 observations: data should match. I think you meant to use transpose `t(scores.eg)`.

Comment: OK, you fixed `scores.eg.env`. Now it works with me when I try with the current development version of **vegan** (2.6-0).

Comment: @JariOksanen could it be that I'm using earlier vegan versions that don't process NAs in the matrix? (using vegan version 2.4-5)

Comment: I really don't know. Version 2.4-5 is so long history for me that I don't remember. However, 2.6-0 (that I use as it is the one that I develop) changes adonis/adonis2 and it may be that also current release (2.5-5) version fails. I don't know. From my point of view, the problem is fixed if it is fixed in the latest development version.